# How to handle conditional data.frame subscripts that contain NAs?

Tags: r, conditional-statements, missing-data, na

Is there a way to have conditional subscripts if the conditional vector contains NAs? 
Assume i have a data.frame like this

```
dframe <- data.frame(a=c(1,32,4,5,8),b=c(1,2,3,4,5),d=c(NA,5,5,10,9))
dframe[dframe$d > 9,"a"] <- NA
```

If it was not for the NA in dframe$d this would be straight forward. I have seen `%in%` syntax like [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-June/165760.html) to get around NAs, but do not know how to manage it for conditions.
I can see that this is somewhat of a general problem, since I am not quite sure whether I want to obtain an NA for the missing value in the condition or something else. 
But I am also interested to learn how people handle this situation.

In my specific situation in would simply be helpful when NA was treated like FALSE in the condition.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can just restrict your indexing to the non NA values

```
dframe[ dframe$d > 9 & !is.na(dframe$d), "a"] <- NA
```

---

**Edit:** Here is a more compact alternative from the [R Inferno](https://www.burns-stat.com/pages/Tutor/R_inferno.pdf):

```
dframe[ which(dframe$d > 9), "a"] <- NA
```

Answer (score 5):

You were close. You had the condition and `%in%`. Just not the link. It is straightforward actually. Just use `%in%` with `TRUE` it'll give back all other values, where as `NA` will be replaced with `FALSE`

```
 dframe[(dframe$d > 9) %in% TRUE, "a"] <- NA
```

Comment: wow, actually I did not have a chance to find that. Even if I was close. +1, though I go with kith here, cause it's easier to remember for me.